# Java reading characters

Tags: java, character

So far im familiar with, toLowerCase() , and toUpperCase(). Let's say I had a question that returned the opposite of every character, to upper to lower and lower to upper. Example

STRing --> strING, how does java know if a character is capitalized or not?

Comment: Do you mean like `Character.isUpperCase` and `Character.isLowerCase` ?

Comment: Yes Why do I need 15 character lmao

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of ways that you can determine if a character is upper or lower case in Java. Java does provide a set of utility methods that you can use to perform the test. See [Character.isUpperCase(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase(char)) and [Character.isLowerCase(char)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase(char))

Characters in Java are ASCII. Each letters is represented by an number and so we can perform arithmetic comparisons to see if the letter is in a range. This means you can do the test yourself as well:

```
public boolean isLowerCase(char c) {
    return c <= 'z' &&  c >= 'a';
}

public boolean isUpperCase(char c) {
    return c <= 'Z' &&  c >= 'A';
}
```

We can put these methods into action in conjunction with String.charAt:

```
public Result countCaseWithCharAt(String sentence) {
    Result result = new Result();

    for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++  ) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(sentence.charAt(i))) {
            result.lowerCaseCount++;
        } else if(Character.isUpperCase(sentence.charAt(i))){
            result.upperCaseCount++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

static class Result {
    public int lowerCaseCount = 0;
    public int upperCaseCount = 0;
}
```

Since you are attempting to switch the characters you may want to utilize another method in String other than charAt, however. You can use String.toCharArray() in order to generate an intermediate structure of each character in the String.

```
public Result countCaseWithCharAtAndArray(String sentence) {
    char[] characters = sentence.toCharArray();
    Result result = new Result();
    for(char current : characters) {
        if(Character.isLowerCase(current)) {
            result.lowerCaseCount++;
        } else if(Character.isUpperCase(current)){
            result.upperCaseCount++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In the example about we iterate through that intermediate structure of characters. Since we created this structure we don't have to perform the extraction from the string for each character and we don't have iterate using those silly integers.

I know you mentioned that you knew about toUpperCase and toLowerCase but I thought I would mention as well that you can again perform those transformations on your own. Lower case 'a' is a greater value in the ASCII table than upper case 'A'. So we we do something like: `'a' - 'A'` we would get the difference between the two. This means we can uppercase a letter by subtracting that value from a letter. `lowerCaseCharacter + ('a' - 'A')` or lower case your character by doing the opposite `upperCaseCharacter - ('a' - 'A')`. I don't think you should do this but you can.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is...

```
if (Character.toUpperCase(c) == c){
    c = Character.toLowerCase(c);
} else {
    c = Character.toUpperCase(c);
}
```

Comment: How about `Character.isUpperCase()`?

Answer (score 0):

Well...the simplest way to achieve this is by doing the following:

1. Check the case of each letter
2. Based on each case, use one of the two methods **you** described in your question:

   toLowerCase() 
   toUpperCase()

based on what case the character is.

---

**So, lets say we come across an upper case character. What do we want to do? We want to make it lowercase. We can say that in an if statement:**

```
if(we come across an upper case letter)
Make it a lowercase letter!
```

**Now, lets say we come across an lower case character. What do we want to do? We want to make it upercase. We can say that in an if statement:**

```
if(we come across an lower case letter)
Make it an uppercase letter!
```

So, now we got the logic down. **In programming, it's important to know what you're going to do, before you do it.** So, how do we represent those two if statements in actual java code?

Well, this is for the first one, `uppercase -> lowercase`:

```
if (Character.isUpperCase(a)){ //This means, it is already uppercase
a = Character.toLowerCase(a); //Lets make it lowercase!
```

And this is for the second one! `lowercase -> uppercase`:

```
if (Character.isLowerCase(a)){ //This means, it is already lowercase
    a = Character.toLowerCase(a); //Lets make it lowercase!
```

This is where, you are iterating through your string, and a is the character of your string!

If this was useful, please mark it best answer (check mark under like button). If you have anymore questions, feel free to ask, I am happy to help.